Could not find the project main file inside of the workspace config
I've got this error Could not find the project main file inside of the workspace config (src) trying to install angular-calendar with the command ng add angular-calendar
ng add angular-calendar
Skipping installation: Package already installed
? What date adapter would you like to use? date-fns        [ https://date-fns.org/ ]
? Please enter a path to the NgModule that will use the calendar. It should be relative to the root project directory, for example src/app/app.module.ts (optional, will use the root app module if not 
specified) 
? Please enter the name of the project that will use the calendar (optional, will use the default project if not specified) frontend
    Added "angular-calendar" into dependencies
    Added "date-fns" into dependencies
    Installing angular calendar dependencies...
    Add modules imports options...
Could not find the project main file inside of the workspace config (src)
(base) baba@baba:~/pfe/template/frontend$ 

